# PS3 sending bad data over HDMI?

Tags: ps3

Within the last two weeks or so (I think since I last did a system update), my PS3 has on occasion been causing my television to freak out and stop accepting commands via remote control **and** the buttons on the face of the television itself, until I pull out and plug back in the TV's power cable.  What happens is that, as the PS3 turns on, I hear a couple of beeps from the TV as if it's changing inputs, and the TV briefly shows the selected input on the screen.  A couple seconds later, I'll sometimes hear another beep and see the same thing on the screen, and then I'll notice that the TV no longer responds to volume changes, nor any other command (such as input changes or even the power button).  The video image displays just fine, though.

The TV is an **LG 47LE5500**, and thinking the HDMI cable might have been going bad, I replaced it but still had the problem.  I then tried switching HDMI ports, to see if the HDMI input that I had plugged the PS3 into was bad.  The problem remained, however.  Since I also have a Windows-based DVR plugged into a third HDMI port on the TV and have no such problems when watching that, I've concluded that it's the PS3 that's causing this.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?  It seems like my PS3, upon powering on, is sending garbage data over HDMI which is causing my TV to lock up.  I took a quick look at the video settings on the PS3 but didn't see anything that looked odd that might cause my issue.

**Update on 7/10/14:**

My DVR is now causing the same problem with my television, so it is definitely the TV that is causing the problem.  As I point out below, keeping the resolution at 720p gets around the issue, though it's not ideal.

Comment: You might want to try your luck on [the Super User StackExchange](http://superuser.com/) which will probably have users more qualified on your problem than on Arqade ;)

Comment: If you've replaced the cable, chances are pretty good it's something to do with the TV itself.

Comment: Did you spend the same amount on time looking at your PS3 and your other devices plugged to your TV? My underlying idea is that your TV may be overheating, but the problem only appear with the PS3 because you play for several hours.

Comment: Good ideas everyone.  @A.L - excellent point, though this happens upon a cold boot up of my PS3.  I really only use it for Netflix streaming and watching Blu-ray discs and very rarely game on it, so overheating shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also, I don't appear to be alone with this problem with an LG TV.  [This video](http://youtu.be/id85AUJdF1M) demonstrates this same issue with a different LG model, and someone in the comments noted that the same thing happens to their LG TV when using their PS3.  No one suggested a good solution, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've done all the research already.

The only other two steps I can think of at this point:

- Try another PS3.
- Try to connect to another TV.

The other possibility here is that your TV is going bad for whatever reason. It could be that the PS3's HDCP handshake is throwing the TV off, or some other data that it's trying to send. Trying another known-good device would confirm this though.

In either case, I'm sure a Component connection wouldn't have an issue. Otherwise it's just a matter of replacing whichever device is going bad, there's not really much you can do yourself to fix it.

Comment: These are excellent ideas and really the only troubleshooting steps left to find out which piece is the problematic hardware, so I'm marking this as the answer.  That being said, I don't know anyone near me without another PS3 I can try out, and my only other flat screen television is an old clunker that has had some HDMI issues in the past.  Incidentally, it worked fine with my PS3 when I tried it a moment ago.  I do suspect though like Frank suggests above that the TV is at fault.

Comment: Also, in case this helps anyone else, I did find a sort of undesirable workaround for the time being (I'm eventually upgrading my old A/V receiver which I no longer use, and hopefully putting the new one between the two devices will eliminate my problem).  I spent a good hour trying out different things with my TV and PS3, such as the order and delay in which they were turned on, and I ultimately found that by limiting my PS3 to 720p resolution, my TV stopped freaking out.  I of course would prefer 1080p, but at least I don't need to go run out and buy a new TV now.

Comment: In that case, another question that comes to mind: "Does your DVR output on 1080p or 720p?".

Comment: Great question - my DVR does in fact output 1080p.  I haven't experienced this problem when using it with the TV, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried disabling LG's SimpLink feature? or the HDMI-CEC(or equivalent) in the other devices?**

SimpLink is LG's propietary version of the HDMI-CEC standard, and it is supposed to let you control **all devices** from **one remote control**.

The problem is that nearly all manufacturers **stray** from the specification, and this could lead to devices getting confused.

With my LG tv, and my PS3, there were weird things happening, since Sony's implementation of CEC and SimpLink weren't compatible.

I disabled the HDMI-CEC in the PS3 ;)

**EDIT:** What kind of DVR is it? Do you have any HDMI-CEC protocol enabled in this device too? is that protocol compatible with LG's SimpLink?

Comment: Good suggestion - it's possible that was part of the problem.  Unfortunately, the HDMI inputs on this TV all went bad about 4 months back (they all stopped working at the same time, apparently a somewhat common occurrence with the circuit board of this line of LG televisions), and then all rest of the inputs stopped working a couple weeks ago (a loud burst of static, followed by the TV shutting down on its own, resulted in all inputs stating "Invalid Format" when the TV was turned back on).  I ended up giving away the television for spare parts, so I can't confirm what my HDMI-CEC setup was.

Comment: Long story short: the circuitry in the television is entirely suspect and probably caused all my grief.